# How to pass getCredentials argument into VS-generated [proj].Deploy.cmd file?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, msdeploy

How to pass getCredentials argument into the auto-generated deployment file [proj].Deploy.cmd (generated by VS2010 SP1)?